# Plotly - Change Layout Background Color Area Under Y axis (y <= 0)

Tags: plotly

I have a faceted plot and I want to shade the area under y-axis to another color Without have to set the scale range of the y-axis.

Using `fig.update_layout(plot_bgcolor="#4503fc")` will change the whole plot background color as I only want to change the color of area below y axis.

Using `add_hrect` will fixed the y-scale as it requires `y0` and `y1` parameters. Any ideas where I can shade area where `y <= 0`?

```
fig = px.line(
    df, 
    y="earnings_diff", 
    x="month_year", 
    color="territory",
    facet_row = "hours",
    facet_col = "days",
    title="""<b>Title</b>""",
    markers=True,
    labels = {
        'earnings_diff': 'Earning Differences',
        'month_year': 'Month',
        'hours': 'hours a day',
        'days': 'days a month'
        },
    height=1000
    )

fig.update_layout(
template='plotly', 
showlegend=True,
title_x=0.5,
legend=dict(
    orientation="h",
    yanchor="bottom",
    y=1.02,
    xanchor="right",
    x=1),
plot_bgcolor='red'

)
fig.add_hrect(y0=0, y1=-50000, line_width=0, fillcolor="red", opacity=0.2)
```

Comment: Which plot do you have to shade y <0? could you add a code or example to your question please?

Comment: How to determine the value of y1?

Comment: code already added

Comment: that's the issue, `add_hrect()` seem not working for this case because y1 doesn't matter. I only want to shade area where y <= 0.

Comment: You can set the value of y1 = df.y.min() if you are sure that you have negative values in the df.y.